# What is a 'double' string type?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Regarding the "types" parameter for the function mysqli_stmt_bind_param. What is a "double" string? It is written in the table in the php manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: A double is not a string, it's a separate data-type.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 6):

The documentation says "double" next to "string", "integer" and "blob".

A `double` is a "double-precision" floating point number, so called because originally floating-point numbers were 32-bits, called `single`s, but we needed more precision so they widened it to 64-bits and called them `doubles` (I personally would have preferred the names `ieee32` and `ieee64` respectively but oh well).

So a `double` is not a string at all. An `integer` is a whole-number, and a `blob` is a Binary-Large-OBject, essentially arbitrary data of variable length.